# Resize an already drawn Inkstrokes in InkCanvas

Tags: uwp, directx, transform, inkcanvas, win2d

I am drawing a rectangle boundary after selecting a specific stroke that I have drawn with a mouse click. After that, I want to resize the rectangle via dragging the corners of the rectangle. At the same time, I want **to resize the stroke bounded by the rectangle** as well.

For scaling, I tried to use 
`Matrix3x2 scale1 = Matrix3x2.CreateScale(2.0f);
foreach(var stroke in strokes)
{
     stroke.PointTransform = scale1;
}`

But As I understood, When scaling. it uses the original coordinate system. ( I have marked the original coordinate system in the upper left corner of the second picture)

Is there a way to change the coordinate system when scaling? May be any matrix calculation?

If someone is downgrading my question, Please tell me why, So I can improve myself and rephrase the question.
**[Note: I'm using Custom Drying and Win2D to render InkStrokes, Application is written in C# for UWP]**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a way to do this.
Let assume, we are moving the bottom right corner for resizing.

1. Get and Draw the bounding Rect using SelectWithLine or SelectWithPolyLine functions. (This will set the Selected parameter of strokes to True as well)
2. Get the scaling factors of xScale and yScale with the OnPointerMoved.
3. With the movement of Pointer, redraw the stroke and bounding Rect.
4. Scaling should be done as follows. (Maintain variables[xScalePrev, yScalePrev] to track whether both axes scaled with the pointer movement)

   ```
               if (xScalePrev != xScale & yScalePrev != yScale)
               {
                   Matrix3x2 scale1 = Matrix3x2.CreateScale(1 + (float)xScale, 1 + (float)yScale);
                   Matrix3x2 a = stroke.PointTransform * scale1;
                   float xOffset = a.M31 - (float)boundingRect.Left * (float)xScale;
                   float yOffset = a.M32 - (float)boundingRect.Top * (float)yScale;
                   stroke.PointTransform = new Matrix3x2(a.M11, a.M12, a.M21, a.M22, xOffset, yOffset);

                   xScalePrev = xScale;
                   yScalePrev = yScale;
               }
               else if (xScalePrev != xScale)
               {
                   Matrix3x2 scale1 = Matrix3x2.CreateScale(1 + (float)xScale, 1);
                   Matrix3x2 a = stroke.PointTransform * scale1;
                   float xOffset = a.M31 - (float)boundingRect.Left * (float)xScale;
                   stroke.PointTransform = new Matrix3x2(a.M11, a.M12, a.M21, a.M22, xOffset, a.M32);

                   xScalePrev = xScale;
               }
               else if (yScalePrev != yScale)
               {
                   Matrix3x2 scale1 = Matrix3x2.CreateScale(1, 1 + (float)yScale);
                   Matrix3x2 a = stroke.PointTransform * scale1;
                   float yOffset = a.M32 - (float)boundingRect.Top * (float)yScale;
                   stroke.PointTransform = new Matrix3x2(a.M11, a.M12, a.M21, a.M22, a.M31, yOffset);

                   yScalePrev = yScale;
               }
   ```

This is how I achieved resizing with the Bottom-Right corner. Similarly, this can be implemented in other corners as well.

Answer (score 1):

Is the coordinate of 'A' you want to use when scaling? From the second picture, you seem to want to scale strokes based on the lower left corner of 'A', then you can create a scaling matrix that is offset by a given center point. For example:

```
var container = inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer;

var bounds = container.BoundingRect;
var center = new Vector2((float)bounds.Left, (float)bounds.Bottom);
var transform = Matrix3x2.CreateScale(2.0f, 2.0f, center);

foreach (var stroke in strokes)
{
    stroke.PointTransform = transform;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, Thank for your answer. I also add an answer when resizing with the bottom right corner. I took the center as Top - left corner.  The thing is when I move the mouse pointer too fast, scaling lags. Do you have any idea about that? I get the x scaling factor by getting the offset x coordinate when pointer moved with respect to the original width of the bounding Rect. Is it a scaling issue or something to do with the pointer movement?

Comment: I noticed you mentioned with the movement of Pointer, you will redraw the stroke and bounding Rect. Maybe multiple renderings in a short time will cause delay, you could try to use a Timer and force redrawing with a fixed time interval(e.g. 80ms) when moving mouse, it will reduce the number of renders and smoother.